# AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter. Arch Linux

Tags: virtual-machine, firmware, amd, antergos

I'm having some problems with an Antergos 4.18 installation on my Acer Swift 3 ([SF315-41](https://www.acer.com/datasheets/2017/4876/SF315-41/NX.GV7ET.001.html)) the main one is regarding virtualization.

At first when I booted up the OS I would get this messages:

```
[Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table
[Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table
```

And the computer would get frozen between 1 to 3 times a day seemingly at random intervals if I was running a VM.

After digging around I found [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/1255206) which helped me get past those errors by following the instructions under the title "2. Linux workaround"

I thought the freeze problems were gone after that but yesterday it happened again, I took a look at the output of `dmesg` and sure enough there is a remaining error regarding AMD-Vi:

```
AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.
```

`dmesg` dumps:

- [Before the SU fix](https://ares.uy/before.html)
- [After the SU fix](https://ares.uy/after.html)

[`inxi -Fxz` output](https://ares.uy/inxi.html)

Comment: Do you fix this problem? I have the same problem.

Comment: @l0o0 I gave up on running Linux on it, here's a thread I've opened in a forum about the issue https://forum.level1techs.com/t/linux-on-the-acer-swift-3-sf315-41-memory-reboot-problems/132414 if you find a solution let me know.

Comment: From this [post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400746&page=2), I added `iommu=soft` to `/etc/default/grub.cfg`, updating grub config. By now, `AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter` error message is gone and the computer does not get stuck.

Comment: @l0o0 that's great, did you read my post on level1techs? on it I discover that my issue seems to have more to do with memory than VMs, are you able to run the command I specify on this post https://forum.level1techs.com/t/linux-on-the-acer-swift-3-sf315-41-memory-reboot-problems/132414/8 for like 30 minutes without any problems?